# Reinitializing git in a new Unity Project Folder, for an existing Repository

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I encountered some weird bug with my Unity Project that could only be fixed by creating a new Unity Project, and then importing all of the assets from the previous project into it.

The old Unity Project is a Git Repository Clone with a .gitignore, and a long history.

I'm trying to reinitialize the new project with the older repository.  I don't know the proper process, and I've had trouble finding the information in my searches.  Perhaps, I just don't know the right keywords.

I tried simply copying over the .git folder and .gitignore file, but for some reason Source Tree is ignoring the .gitignore file.

Edit: I believe I just needed refresh source tree by hitting F5 or going to view>refresh

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to answer my own question, because copying over the .git folder and the .git ignore file and then refreshing source tree seems to have worked.

However, I was still  unable to find information to confirm that I did this correctly, online. So if I may be in error, or if there is a better way, please comment or submit your own answer.